# VM Ubuntu: What are /dev/mapper and /dev/sd1?

Tags: virtualbox, disk-usage

I want to increase the free disk space of my VM Ubuntu (host = Mac 10.10).
After autoclean -> auto remove, I still 80% (=5.7/7.5 GB)of space used in /dev/mapper, however, only 3% (=7.2/246.8 MB) used in /dev/sda1.

Could anyone explain me what are /dev/mapper and /dev/sda1, and their relation with the base memory (=2000MB) of my VM? And how to even increase the free space?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altough this doesn't fully address the question, in order to free up some space I suggest you to first remove the installed packages that are not needed anymore:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Then you can clear the `/var/log` folder, which is extremely prone to grow in size over time, expecially if something at some point didn't work perfectly:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/log/*
```

Then you can use this command to list all your files/folders sorted from the smallest file/folder to the biggest file/folder, in order to quickly spot which files/folders are the biggest so you can possibly free up some additional space:

```
du -ahd <n> / | sort -hr
```

Where `<n>` is a number higher or equal to `0` representing the depth of the search.

`3` should be a number large enough to narrow down the search a bit without having to deal with an excessively large list of files/folders.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `/dev/sda1` is a small conventional boot partition, while `/dev/mapper` contains a LVM2 logical volume consisting of the remainder of the filesystem as a single `root` LV, which would be the normal configuration if you had selected the "Use entire diskwith LVM" option during installation. For instance, my current (non virtual) installation has

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  162G   14G  140G   9% /
/dev/sda1                    236M   66M  158M  30% /boot
```

You would need to provide additional information in your question (such as the output of the command `df -h | grep ^/`) for anyone to know for sure. To increase the free space you would need to remove additional installed software or unneeded data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! My VM Ubuntu crashed last night, and I just re-installed it. Now the output of df -h is:

Comment: /dev/sda1       6.8G  4.9G  1.6G  76% /

Comment: none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

Comment: udev            475M  4.0K  475M   1% /dev

Comment: tmpfs            97M  952K   97M   1% /run

Comment: none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock

Comment: none            485M  8.4M  477M   2% /run/shm

Comment: none            100M   36K  100M   1% /run/user

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to resize your VM mapped drives, without gparted or messing with your files:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/659099/352647